# How to integrate Gitlab into Asana

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, integration, gitlab, asana

Is there already a possibility to integrate gitlab into asana?

Since they moved to oAuth 2.0 I am not able to create API keys anymore.

Someone already created an issue on gitlab. but there is no activity at all =) https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/21576

Does someone know a way to do it?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a Developer Advocate at Asana.

It looks as though there has been some activity recently: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/21576 shows some stuff in the past few days.

In any case, I'll reach out to them to see if I can help them along in any way! Thanks!